# C# Store Class Type in a Dictionary/List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to store the class type and not an instance of a class in my dictionary/list?

I want to do something like this:

```
public class FoodNeed : BaseNeeds
{
    public Dictionary<Type, float> consumptionlist = new Dictionary<Type, float>();

    public FoodNeed()
    {
        consumptionlist.Add (Meat, 0.3f);
    }
}
```

**Meat** is is class and instead of adding a "**new Meat()**" to the dictionaray i just want to store the type (beacause i think it's not necessary to create the complete instace just for the type), is that possible? Or do i have to store for example "Meat" as string and parse this later on. Or is something like this a big no-no and this has to be done differently.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Seems you have already done it, What is the problem?

Comment: Sure, you just need `typeof(Meat)`. Then it should compile.

Comment: omg -.- Matthew Watson THANKS !! That helped !
i always got the error:
Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected
... sorry ... but i'm just a noob xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [**typeof**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) to get the type of meat:

```
public class FoodNeed : BaseNeeds
{
    public Dictionary<Type, float> consumptionlist = new Dictionary<Type, float>();

    public FoodNeed()
    {
        consumptionlist.Add(typeof(Meat), 0.3f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `typeof`,

```
public class FoodNeed : BaseNeeds
{
    public Dictionary<Type, float> consumptionlist = new Dictionary<Type, float>();

    public FoodNeed()
    {
        consumptionlist.Add (typeof(Meat), 0.3f);
    }
}
```